# subscribe to a function, which returns observable only in if clause

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an if clause which checks the window global object whether cordova is present, and if so, it will perform a http request and return the default angular 2 http observable.

If the app is in web context, cordova won't exist so the function should do nothing.

However in order to subscribe to it, I need to return an observable or I will get the can't subscribe to null error. My current solution is to return Observable.empty(),

but is that safe or is there something more elegant? Thanks!

```
public init():Observable<Response>{
  if(window.cordova){
    return this.http.get(...)
  } else {
    return Observable.empty()
  }
}
```

this is the code, and notice that I need to change  to  to make it work...Is there a way to return Observable?

Comment: Have you tried with `Observable<Response>.from([])`? Or with your setup you can change return type to `:Observable<any>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear whats your problem right now.. :)

`return Observable.of(null);` ?

`return Observable.of(undefined);` ?